# Using str_replace only if conditions are met

Tags: php

I'm doing str_replace on a variable containing a HTML string. The aim is to add "data-rel="external" target="_blank"" to all the a-href's.

```
$html = str_replace("<a href=", "<a data-rel=\"external\" target=\"_blank\" href=", $html);
```

It works fine, but here's the challenge: If the original a-href is a a-href="mailto:[..], then it should add "data-rel="external" target="_system"".

Example:

```
<a href="http://apache.org">Link 1</a>
```

should become:

```
<a data-rel="external" target="_blank" href="http://apache.org">Link 1</a>
```

And

```
<a href="mailto:post@apache.org">Link 2</a>
```

should become:

```
<a data-rel="external" target="_system" href="mailto:post@apache.org">Link 2</a>
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Have you considered using [an XML parser](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)?

Comment: So use DOMDocument then.

Comment: why not just do 2 search and replaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run a mailto str_replace first,

```
$html = str_replace("<a href=\"mailto:", 
    "<a data-rel=\"external\" target=\"_system\" href=\"mailto:", $html);
```

After this has executed, these will no longer be affected by a str_replace looking for `<a href` because they will be `<a data-rel`.

Comment: Thanks! That's so obvious, can't believe I didn't see it myself :)

Comment: No problem. If the use case becomes more complex I'd suggest a more complex parsing solution but for this one it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would test for the appearance of the substring `"mailto:"` within `$html`, and run different `str_replace` commands depending on whether or not that is true.

Comment: I see, but the $html string will probably contain lots of different links, often being a mix of regular links and mailto: links.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I would recommend @Oshawott's answer, then.

Answer (score 0):

In other cases where you couldn't use str_replace, preg_replace might become handy :

```
preg_replace('/<a href="mailto/', '<a data-rel="external" target="_system" href="mailto', $html);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
<?php
$html='<a href="http://apache.org">Link 1</a><a href="mailto:post@apache.org">Link 2</a>';
$html = str_replace('<a href="mailto', '<a data-rel="external" target="_system" href="mailto', $html);
$html = str_replace('<a href=', '<a data-rel="external" target="_blank" href=', $html);
echo $html;
?>
```

or this

```
<?php
$html='<a href="http://apache.org">Link 1</a><a href="mailto:post@apache.org">Link 2</a>';
$html = str_replace(array('<a href="mailto','<a href='), array('<a data-rel="external" target="_system" href="mailto','<a data-rel="external" target="_blank" href='), $html);
echo $html;
?>
```

output

```
<a data-rel="external" target="_blank" href="http://apache.org">Link 1</a>
<a data-rel="external" target="_system" href="mailto:post@apache.org">Link 2</a>
```